# ContentProvider:[Unknown Uri] invoke call(String, String, Bundle) while the app is dead

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I encountered a strange issue recently.
The basic information is the app is dead, and I registered a ContentProvider in my AndroidManifest.
the issue is:
when I code getContentResolver().call(target-uri(which is correct),...,...,...) in third-party app, and then the third-party app will go crash immediately, which is caused by Unknown Uri, but this problem won't happen when I keep the uri-target application alive.  Besides, the issue is not showing neither when I go getContentResolver().query()。
Therefore, Could anyone tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on **EMUI** device? It may be the system cause.

If you are working on **EMUI** device: 
(1) Go to **Settings** > **Apps** > **Apps** > **[Target App Name]** > **Battery usage details** > **App launch**. 
(**设置>应用>应用管理>你的目标应用名>耗电详情>应用启动管理**)
(2) Disable Manage automatically and check **Secondary launch** or **Run in background**.
**允许关联启动或者允许后台启动**
After set that, my app in EMUI device is run correctly.
 I don't know why the problem occurred in EMUI device. May be it is limited by the EMUI develop department to prevent battery usage issue.
The above is not a good way to solve the problem. But it's the only way I can make it work now.I have to compromise.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I was not working on EMUI, the situation that I encountered could be accepted, so I gave up tracing the issue.

Comment: Sorry for that. Even you are not working in EMUI device,Try alow triggered start or auto start in any device may help if you still focus on it.
By the way, May I ask you what device cause the situation in your side?